# The value labels in seaborn countplot / factorplot are displayed as values in other graphs

Tags: python, graph, label, seaborn, countplot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
 
sns.countplot(data=train_dt, x='Pclass', ax=ax)

abs_values = train_dt['Pclass'].value_counts()
rel_values = train_dt['Pclass'].value_counts(normalize=True).values * 100
lbls = [f'{p[0]} ({p[1]:.0f}%)' for p in zip(abs_values, rel_values)]

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge', labels=lbls)
 
plt.show()
```

When you run the code above, the graph will look like the one below.

The values themselves aren't wrong, but the graph and labels don't match.
[image]

What did I do wrong?

First, a word of thanks.

Comment: You'd get the same order for the labels with `train_dt['Pclass'].value_counts(..., sort=False)`. Or, alternatively, use the order of the labels for the count plot: `sns.countplot(..., order=train_dt['Pclass'].value_counts().index)`

Comment: Thank you very much, you have solved this problem. However, the `sort=False` method didn't work for me. Is there any way to do this while maintaining the 1, 2, 3 order?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?  Does it give an error?  Is the order still wrong? What is the output of `print(train_dt['Pclass'].value_counts(sort=False))`?

Comment: The output will be the same as the image above. :)

Comment: Does `print` output an image? Is `Pclass` a numeric or a categorical column in your dataframe?